# How to calculate the sum of rows by each gvkey respectively?

Tags: r

I tried to calculate the cumulative sum of the twitter followers for each gvkey respectively ,and I use the group_by function,but the output is still the sum of the entire column,I suppose it is the problem of the " for (i in i:nrow(premod_e))

```
 predmod_e <- predmod_e %>%
      arrange(gvkey, date) %>%#arrange the gvkey and date
      group_by(gvkey)#use group_by for respective calculation
      for (i in 1:nrow(predmod_e)) {
        predmod_e[i+1,]$x <- predmod_e[i+1,]$x + predmod_e[i,]$x
      }#for loop to calculate
```

Comment: Please edit your question so that it is readable. Use code chunk just for code. Format your code properly so that it is readable.

Comment: use a fuction `cumsum` in the `dplyr`, chain with the first part of the code

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just this:

```r
 predmod_e <- predmod_e %>%
      arrange(gvkey, date) %>%
      group_by(gvkey) %>%
      mutate(newx = cumsum(x))
```

If you want to do something with the groups *yourself* (i.e., not with a `dplyr` verb), then you should use the groups as they are "known" by the tidy verbs. Luckily, they are merely stored as an attribute:

```r
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  attr(., "groups")
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#     cyl .rows     
#   <dbl> <list>    
# 1     4 <int [11]>
# 2     6 <int [7]> 
# 3     8 <int [14]>
```